# How can I call a method on and Ivar

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, ivar

I have some code which gives me an `Ivar`.

```
// written some code so now I have the following Ivar
Ivar ivar = i_have_an_ivar;
```

I can get the type of this Ivar by calling `ivar_getTypeEncoding` method so I know what type is this Ivar. Now I want to call a method on this Ivar. How can I do that?

Comment: @to the guy who decided to down vote but did not care to leave a comment for why: Is there something wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object_getIvar (id object, Ivar ivar)` is the answer. this will give me the object and then I can call a method on that object.